# How can I make x=y in terms of value and not memory?

Tags: python

I need a little help understanding this code:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
x = y
print x
print y
y.remove(4)
print x
print y
```

When I remove `4` from the list `[4,5,6]`, both the `x` and `y` variables will point to the same `[5,6]` list in memory am I right?
If so, then how can I make `x` equal to a replica of the `y` list so that `x` and `y` both point to different places in memory yet those places both hold the same value? (As opposed to them both pointing to the same place in memory as seen above)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For lists in particular, you can make a shallow copy by taking a slice of the whole list:

```
x = y[:]
```

This isn't guaranteed to work for arbitary sliceable objects (eg, numpy array slices don't create a new array), so it can be useful to use the builtin [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copy.html) module:

```
import copy
x = copy.copy(y)
```

can be expected to work for an arbitary `y`.

Answer (score 7):

Just clone the list:

```
x = list(y)
```

Comment: Arguably this is the most readable method, and applies to `dict` and `set` as well

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6]
>>> x = y[:]
>>> y.remove(4)
>>> y
[5, 6]
>>> x
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
x = y[:]
print x
print y
y.remove(4)
print x
print y
```

So [:] makes a copy of a list.